# What Does .size mean

Tags: ruby, windows

What does `target.size` mean in the below code and what does `w` mean that is next to the  filename? And when I remove `w` or `.size` the program what does that mean?

```
filename = ARGV.first
    script = $0

    puts "We're going to erase #{filename}."
    puts "If you don't wnat that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
    puts "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

    print "? "
    STDIN.gets

    puts "Opening the file..."
    target = File.open(filename,'w')

    puts "Truncating the file. Goodbye!"
    target.truncate(target.size)

    puts "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

    print "line 1: "; line1 = STDIN.gets.chomp()
    print "line 2: "; line2 = STDIN.gets.chomp()
    print "line 3: "; line3 = STDIN.gets.chomp()

    puts "I'm going to write these to the file"

    target.write(line1)
    target.write("\n")
    target.write(line2)
    target.write("\n")
    target.write(line3)
    target.write("\n")
    puts "And finally, we Close it"
    target.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

[`File.open(filename,'w')`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-open) gives you a [`File`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html) object, which is assigned to the local variable `target`.`target.size` means actually [`File#size`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-i-size), which *Returns the size of file in bytes.* If you don't supply the mode as `'w'`, then the file will be opened with mode `'r'`, which is a default mode.

---

Read [**IO Open Mode**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode) :

`"w"` :

> *Write-only, truncates existing file to zero length or creates a new file for writing.*

---

> Explanation of the line `target.truncate(target.size)`.

Here you actually called [`File#truncate`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-i-truncate), what this method does is *Truncates file to at most integer bytes*. That means you are deleting the file contents fully and making the file size as *zero*.

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand it i am professional at ruby sorry
can you make it simpler

Comment: w = writable
but what does size mean and why did the code didn't crash when i remove .size

Comment: It wouldn't. because what you are doing is, just deleting the old contents, then adding new contents into that file..